# Pagination with Page numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a page which get's populated dynamically from a Mysql database.

To prevent to much information been displayed at once, I have added pagination to page.

Using this code.

```
$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$maxRows_atoz = 10; $page= 0;
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {$page= $_GET['page'];}
$startRow_atoz = $page* $maxRows_atoz;

mysql_select_db($database_main, $main);
$query_atoz = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE title LIKE 'A%'"; 
$query_limit_atoz = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_atoz, $startRow_atoz, $maxRows_atoz);
$atoz = mysql_query($query_limit_atoz, $main) or die(mysql_error());
$row_atoz = mysql_fetch_assoc($atoz);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_atoz'])) {$totalRows_atoz = $_GET['totalRows_atoz'];} else {$all_atoz = mysql_query($query_atoz); $totalRows_atoz = mysql_num_rows($all_atoz);}
$totalPages_atoz = ceil($totalRows_atoz/$maxRows_atoz)-1;
$queryString_atoz = ""; if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {$params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); $newParams = array(); foreach ($params as $param) {
if (stristr($param, "pageNum_atoz") == false && stristr($param, "totalRows_atoz") == false) {array_push($newParams, $param);}}
if (count($newParams) != 0) {$queryString_atoz = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));}}    
$queryString_atoz = sprintf("&totalRows_atoz=%d%s", $totalRows_atoz, $queryString_atoz);

?>

<ul>
<li class="previous"> <?php if ($page > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
<a title="See Previous 10 Results" href="<?php printf("?page=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $page - 1), $queryString_atoz); ?>">
<img src="/files/previous.png" /></a>
<?php } // Show if not first page ?></li>
<li class="next">  <?php if ($page < $totalPages_atoz) { // Show if not last page ?>
<a title="See Previous 10 Results" href="<?php printf("?page=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_atoz, $page + 1), $queryString_atoz); ?>">
<img src="/files/next.png" /></a>
<?php } // Show if not last page ?></li>
</ul>
```

The code works in paginaing the results, but has a limitation.
It currently only display's Next and Previous buttons.

I would like to add page numbers. This way a user can skip to 4th or 5th page in the result set rather than having to press the next button 4 or 5 times.

So, can some please tell me how I would go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I must say, I havent gone through the entire code of yours. You must indent your code to help others. If I get your question right, the following may help you. I haven't much taken care of finer details. This is just to give you an idea. :-)

```
<ul>
<li class="previous">
<?php if ($page > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
<a title="See Previous 10 Results" href="<?php printf("?page=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $page - 1),$queryString_atoz); ?>">
<img src="/files/previous.png" /></a>
<?php } // Show if not first page ?></li>
<!--MODIFY_BEGIN-->
<li>
<?php for ($i=0;$i<$page; $i++){
    if ($currentPage==$i)
        echo ($currentPage+1);
    else
        echo "<a title='Page $i' href='?page=$i'>Page $i</a>";
} ?>

</li>
<!--MODIFY_END-->
<li class="next">  <?php if ($page < $totalPages_atoz) { // Show if not last page ?>
<a title="See Previous 10 Results" href="<?php printf("?page=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_atoz, $page + 1), $queryString_atoz); ?>">
<img src="/files/next.png" /></a>
<?php } // Show if not last page ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Thrustmaster, your code works sort off. The pages numbers only show after clicking the next button and not straight away. So when $currentPage = ?page=06 I see Page 1, Page 2, Page3, Page 4, Page 5. However if $currentPage = ?page=01 nothing shows. So the user does't have the option to skip ahead. Hope that makes sense.